# Is setTimeout() in JavaScript synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, settimeout

I have the following function that utilises the `setTimeout()` function

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
    someElement.classList.remove('active');
    someElement.classList.remove('active--show');
    setTimeout(function () {
        someElement.classList.remove('some--class')
    }, 3000);
    someElement.classList.remove('another--class');
    someElement.classList.remove('and--another--class');
    someElement.classList.remove('and--another--class--again');
});
```

Does the current function carry on running the following commands *(code snippet below)* when reaching the `setTimeout()` function and once 3 seconds have passed run the script inside the `setTimeout()` function?

```
someElement.classList.remove('another--class');
someElement.classList.remove('and--another--class');
someElement.classList.remove('and--another--class--again');
```

Or does it get to the `setTimeout()` function, wait 3 seconds, then run the script inside it then carry on with the rest of the original function?

Appreciate any advice on this.

Thank you

Comment: setTimeout is non-blocking. The next statement is executed immediately Why not use the console to test your theory

Comment: The first of the scenarios you described.

Comment: @mplungjan  thanks for the link to the other question that helps me understand better. I am fairly new to javascript, using the console would have been a good choice my bad there! Thanks again

Comment: I don't think either of those "duplicate" questions answers this question - at least not directly.

Comment: The last 3lines will be executed and will not be blocked by setTimeout.